# Dividing two SQL Selects Statements and grouping the result by a date field (or category)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get a % of windows servers that are also SQL Servers over time from a table. While I can get the math for the aggregate, I can not get the GROUP BY to work to calculate for each unique report date. Is there anther another way to do this? I didn't want to use the case function because the report date is iterative and dynamic (timestamp) and I would have to modify the statement every time a new report was generated.

Here's my data set:

```
[IP Address] | [OS] | [SQL Server] | [Report Date]
127.1.1.0 | Win2k12 | 1 | 9/1/2016
127.1.1.1 | Win2k12 | 0  | 9/1/2016
127.1.1.3 | Win2k12 | 1  | 9/1/2016
127.1.1.4 | Win2k12 | 0  | 9/1/2016
127.1.1.5 | Win2k12 | 0  | 9/1/2016
127.1.1.0 | Win2k12 | 1  | 10/1/2016
127.1.1.1 | Win2k12 | 0  | 10/1/2016
127.1.1.3 | Win2k12 | 1  | 10/1/2016
127.1.1.4 | Win2k12 | 0  | 10/1/2016
127.1.1.5 | Win2k12 | 0  | 10/1/2016
127.1.1.6 | Win2k12 | 0  | 10/1/2016
127.1.1.7 | Win2k12 | 1  | 10/1/2016
```

Here's what I have thus far:

```
SELECT
           (SELECT CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT [IP Address]) AS FLOAT(4))
            FROM    ediscov_report
            WHERE  [SQL Server] = 1
                 AND (DATEPART(MONTH, (DATEADD(M, +2, [Report Date]))) = (DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE())))
                 AND (DATEPART(YEAR, [Report Date]) = (DATEPART(year, GETDATE()))));

(SELECT CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT [IP Address]) AS FLOAT(4))
 FROM   ediscov_report
 WHERE  (DATEPART(MONTH, (DATEADD(M, +2, [Report Date]))) = (DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE())))
       AND (DATEPART(YEAR, [Report Date]) = (DATEPART(year, GETDATE()))));
```

Here is the result I am trying to get:

```
[Report Date] | [PCT SQL]<BR> 9/1/2016 | .4<BR> 10/1/2016 | .428571
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this with simple aggregation functions:

```
Select ReportDate,
       count(*) as numservers,
       sum(SQLServer) as num_SQLServers,
       avg(SQLServer * 1.0) as p_SQLSever
From ediscov_report 
group by ReportDate
order by ReportDate;
```

Comment: That is close but I'm not getting the right numbers. Main reason is because there are duplicates in the report. The same server may show up multiple times. I changed the count(*) to count(distinct IP Address) and that gave me the right number of servers but the duplicates are impacting the numbers for Sum SQLServer and the average. If we can figure out a way to make the math for unique hosts, we should get the right values then. I'll play around with this and see if I can figure it out. Thanks for the help though! I wouldn't have thought to try this approach.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer for the purposes of this example. With the data set I provided as an example, this works flawlessly. But the real data set I have has duplicate rows that throw the calculations off. Thanks for your help on this! I think I know how I need to approach it now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following query

```
SELECT [Report Date], (SQLServer/TotalServer) as Percentage FROM (
SELECT [Report Date], 
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT[IP Address]) FROM ediscov_report WHERE [SQL Server]=1) as SQLServer,
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [IP Address]) FROM ediscov_report) as TotalServer
from ediscov_report 
group by [Report Date])
order by [Report Date]
```

Comment: Can you explain your solution a bit?

Comment: This is really close too. The issue I'm having is that the Percentage field is resolving to 1 or 0 as an int data type. I tried wrapping a cast around it to convert to a float but that's not working either. The result I got came out as 9/1/2016 | 0 and 10/1/2016 | 0 for Report Date and Percentage column.

Comment: Hi, try this new query

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post the solution I came up with for my real data set in the event someone has the same problem with duplicate rows. In my case the scan report may have multiple rows of unique information tied back to the same IP address.

Select ReportDate,
      count(distinct [IP Address]) as numHosts,
      count(distinct (case when [SQLServer]=1 then [IP Address] end)) as numSQLServer,
     cast(count(distinct (case when [SQLServer]=1 then [IP Address] end))as float(4))/cast(count(distinct [IP Address])as float(4)) as p_SQLServer
From ediscov_report
group by ReportDate
order by ReportDate;